# datalist must be refresh without postback when record inserted into table in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

My table is:

```
student

Roll_number  name
1            farhat
2            rupali
```

I want to fetch this record in `datalist`. Actually I get record properly but whenever I insert record then immediately insert that record in `datalist` without any `postback` only `datalist` is refreshed not whole page.

Comment: you can use ajax for this.

Comment: some code will be good :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Ajax Update panel with triggers.

Hope this helps.

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/ajax-updapanel-control-with-triggers.html

Comment: i want to  refresh only datalist without any click not whole page